# Error with 'reticulate' r-package importing python script

Tags: python, r, scipy, reticulate

I'm trying to use "reticulate" package to import 'mycode.py'.
There are many questions on StackOverflow, but no one of them can solve my problem.

I did in 2 ways but I get quite the same error.

1) `source_python("/user/mycode.py")`

and I get this error:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /user/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

2) `import_from_path('mycode', path='/user/', convert=TRUE)`

and I get this error:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /user/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Comment: Is your R inside the same conda installation as Python or separate? There seems to be a conflict between the R Python requiring different library versions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the compatibility between the version of `libstdc++.so` that come with Anaconda and the one installed on your system.

1. Confirm that there is an libstdc++.so.6.0.xx in ~/anaconda3/lib/ (xx is replacement for the latest version, I think 27 is the very latest):

   `ls libstdc++.so.6.0.*`
2. Confirm that there is a symlink libstdc++.so.6 in ~/anaconda3/lib/:

   `ls libstdc++.so.6`
3. Remove the existing symlink (if it points to another version of libstdc++.so):

   `rm ~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6`
4. Relink it to libstdc++.so.6.0.xx:

   `ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.xx libstdc++.so.6`